# C++ cout and cin buffers, and buffers in general

Tags: c++, flush, buffer

Can someone explain the concept of buffers a bit more explicitly? I understand that buffers are data structures where characters are stored, and the place where the data is to be read from. What is the idea of flushing buffers?

When a buffer is flushed, is this referring to the act of writing the characters stored in it?

From the text:

```
To avoid the overhead of writing in response to each output request, the library uses the 
buffer to accumulate the characters to be written, and flushes the buffer, by writing its
contents to the output device, only when necessary. By doing so, it can combine several 
output operations into a single write.
```

When referring to 'flushing' that almost makes it sound as if the buffer is being written but also erased at the same time. Just speculation.

So, in order to be wrote to view on a screen the buffer flush is required?

```
When our program writes its prompt to cout, that output goes into the buffer associated
with the standard output stream. Next, we attempt to read from cin. This read flushes
the cout buffer, so we are assured that our user will see the prompt.
```

Here, it sounds as if the by using 'endl' at the end it tells the system it needs to write immediately(implying otherwise is wouldn't?) What is endl is not used?

```
Writing the value of std::endl ends the line of 
output, and then flushes the buffer, which forces the system to write to the output 
stream immediately.
```

Comment: this question has been asked and answered a lot of time in SO.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/4752069/1155650

Answer (score 27):

The basic idea of buffering is to combine operations into bigger chunks: instead of reading small number of bytes, read an entire page and make this available as requested; instead of writing small number of bytes, buffer them up and write an entire page or when writing is explicitly requested. Essentially, this is an important performance optimization. It pretty clear cut for I/O operations but generally applies for other uses as well: processing multiple units at once generally ends up to be faster than processing individual units.

With respect to I/O *flushing* refers to writing the currently buffered bytes to its destination - whatever this means in practice. For C++ IOStreams flushing a stream amounts to calling the member function `std::ostream::flush()` which in turn calls `std::streambuf::pubsync()` on the associated stream buffer (this ignores the detail that the stream are actually class templates, e.g. `std::basic_ostream<cT, traits>`; for the purpose of this discussion it doesn't matter that they are class templates): the base class `std::streambuf` is C++'s abstraction on how a certain stream is to be processed. It conceptually consists of an input and an output buffer plus virtual function responsible for reading or writing the buffers, respectively. The function `std::streambuf::pubsync()` calls the virtual function `std::streambuf::sync()` which should be overridden for every stream buffer which potentially buffers characters. That is, what *flushing* actually means depends on how this virtual function is implemented.

Whether an override of `sync()` actually does something and what it does clearly depends on what the stream buffer represents. For example, for a `std::filebuf` which is responsible to reading from or writing to a file, `sync()` writes the current content of the buffer and removes the flushed characters from the buffer. Given that a file may not really represent a physical file but e.g. a named pipe to communicate with a different process, this is reasonable behavior. On the other hand, flushing a `std::stringbuf` which is the stream buffer used to implement writing to a `std::string` used e.g. by `std::ostringstream` actually doesn't do anything: the string is entirely within the program and the `std::string` representing its value is constructed when the `std::stringbuf::str()` member function is called. For user defined stream buffers there are many different behaviors. A common class of stream buffers is filtering the output somehow before passing it on to another stream buffer (e.g. a logging buffer may add a time stamp after each newline). These typically just call the `std::streambuf::pubsync()` function of the next stream buffers.

Thus, descriptions of the actual behavior are typically kept fairly vague because it isn't really clear what exactly happens. Conceptually, flushing a stream or calling `pubsync()` on a stream buffer should update the external destination of the character to match the current internal state. Generally, this amounts to forwarding the currently buffered characters and removing them from the internal buffer. At this point it is worth noting that the buffer typically also gets written when it is just full. When it gets full depends, again, on the particular stream buffer. A good implementation of `std::filebuf` will essentially fill a buffer of bytes matching the size of the underlying page (or a multiple thereof) and then write complete pages, minimizing the number of I/O operations needed (this is actually relatively tricky to do because buffer sizes are different between different file systems and depending on the encoding used when writing the number of produced bytes can't be easily estimated).

The standard C++ library typically doesn't require explicit flushes:

- The stream `std::cerr` is set up to automatically flush any output produced after each output operations being called. This is the result of the formatting flag `std::ios_base::unitbuf` being set by default. To turn this off you can use `std::cerr << std::nounitbuf` or your can just use `std::clog` which writes to the same destination but doesn't to do this flushing.
- When reading from an `std::istream` the "tied" `std::ostream`, if any, is flushed. By default `std::cout` is tied to `std::cin`. If you want to set up a tied `std::ostream` yourself you can use e.g. `in.tie(&out)` or, if you want to remove a tied `std::ostream` you can use e.g. `std::cin.tie(0)`.
- When an `std::ostream` is destroyed (or when it would normally destroyed in case the `std::ostream` is one of the standard streams), the `std::ostream` is flushed.
- When a stream's buffer would overflow the virtual function `std::streambuf::overflow()` is called which typically writes the buffer of the current buffer (plus the passed character, if any) to its destination. This often is done by just calling `sync()` to clear out the current buffer but what is done exactly, again, depends on the concrete stream buffer.

You can also explicitly request flushing an `std::ostream`:

- You can call the member function `std::ostream::flush()`, e.g. `std::cout.flush()`.
- You can call the member function `std::streambuf::pubsync()`, e.g. `std::cout.rdbuf()->pubsync()` (assuming there is a stream buffer set up; calling `std::ostream::flush()` will do nothing if there is no stream buffer).
- You can use the manipulator `std::flush`, e.g. `std::cout << std::flush`.
- You can use the manipulator `std::endl`, e.g. `std::cout << std::endl` to first write a newline character followed by flushing the stream. Note that you should use `std::endl` **only** when you really mean to flush the output. **Do not** use `std::endl` when you actually just want to create an end of line! Just write a newline character for the latter!

In any case, if you just write a couple of characters which don't cause the stream buffer's buffer to overflow, nothing will happen with them until they are either implicitly or explicitly flushed. Generally, this isn't a problem because the normal case where buffered output needs to become available, i.e. when reading from `std::cin`, is handled by `std::cout` being `tie()`d to `std::cin`. When there are other I/O mechanisms being used it may be necessary to explicitly `tie()` related streams. The buffer is sometimes a problem if the program "crashes" or asserts during debugging because some outputs to a stream may have been made but weren't, yet, sent. The remedy for this is to use `std::unitbuf`.

Comment: Wow. I am reading your book `The C++ Standard Library` right now!

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Dietmar Kühl. I'm new to C++ and was wondering if you could please explain in layman's terms the difference between the stream object and its associated buffer? I'm trying to understand what happens when we say std::cin >> x when cin is tied to a terminal. I'm very hazy on this, but I think cin "checks" the buffer and if it is empty, it makes a system read call, which blocks execution of the program until input is received. But what happens when I type something into the terminal and press 'Enter' - is the content of the buffer sent to the stream?

Comment: In 'Programming: Principles and Practice' ([page 348](https://www.google.co.nz/books/edition/Programming/We21AwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22When%20you%20use%20an%20istream%22%20stroustrup&pg=PA348&printsec=frontcover)), Stroustrup says, *"When you use an **istream** that is attached to a keyboard, what you type is left in the buffer until you hit Enter (return/newline), and you can use the erase (Backspace) key "to change your mind" (until you hit Enter),"* but it's not clear what happens *after* we press Enter.

Comment: @user51462: the exact details of what happens are pretty much up to the operating system. When a typical C++ program reads input from standard input, it uses some underlying system call, e.g., `read(2)` on POSIX systems, which copies the characters entered using the keyboard into an array of `char`s. This array is typically the buffer used by `std::cin`'s `std::streambuf` which is used to hold the characters at least until they are extracted using something like `std::cin >> value` or `std::getline(std::cin, string)`.

Answer (score 2):

Think of what would happen if, every time you "wrote" a byte to a disk file, your program actually went out to the disk, read in the current sector/cluster/block, changed the single byte then wrote it back to the physical disk.

I'd say your software would be best described as "glacial" in terms of performance :-)

Buffering is a means of batching up reads and writes to make them more efficient.

For example, if you're writing to a disk file, it may wait until you have a full 4K block before writing that to the disk.

When reading, it may get a 4K block even though you only asked for ten bytes, on the assumption that you may ask for the rest shortly.

Flushing on write takes place implicitly once the cache is full or explicitly if requested (with either a flush call or if you close the file).

Note that this file buffering is only *one* sort of buffering, the concept can be used in any place where efficiency gains can be made by "chunking" up the reads and writes.