# Cout in While loop Strange behaviour

Tags: c++

My code look like below

```
int i=0;
while(i<10){
cout<<"Hello";
sleep(1);
i++
}
```

In Windows the code prints on each loop but in Linux it prints everything after exiting while loop . And also if I put an **endl** at the last of **cout** then it prints on each loop. Why this happening ?. Can anyone explain this behavior?.

Comment: Your code reads, "count", not cout?

Comment: Your code is infinite

Comment: Cout works using a buffer. This thread has more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274057/c-cout-and-cin-buffers-and-buffers-in-general

Comment: borisbn is also right. You should copy&paste your complete code. Some important pieces are missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `cout.flush()`; maybe the two OS has different policy in term of buffering the stdout.

Answer (score 1):

For efficiency reasons, sometimes the standard streams will be implemented with a buffer. Making lots of tiny writes can be slow, so it will store up your writes until it gets a certain amount of data before writing it all out at once.

Endl forces it to write out the current buffer, so you'll see the output immediately.

Comment: `endl` forces the output by calling `cout.flush`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 10){
        cout << "Hello" << endl;
        sleep(1);
        ++i;
    }
}
```