# Boost thread showing no output on stdout

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I'm trying to use the boost thread library. Below is a sample code.

For some reason I'm not seeing any output.

```
int main()
{
  myclass Class1;
  while(1) {
  }
}

/************************************/

typedef boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread> thread_ptr;

// class definition

myclass::myclass()
{
    // thread_ptr is of type thread_ptr
    threat_ptr1 = thread_ptr(new boost::thread(&myclass::function_name, this)); 
}
void myclass:function_name()
{
    std::cout << "enter here";
    while( true ) {
        boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(2));
        // do some stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Hope you wiped because you forgot to flush!

Comment: @CaptainObvlious - Surely because you did flush? Away how do blind people know when to stop wiping?

Comment: @EdHeal Bunghole Braille?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Or get a faithful dog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
std::cout << "enter here";
```

use

```
std::cout << "enter here" << std::endl;
```

Flushing is your friend ;-)

As a sidenote, in production you *should not* use `while(1){}` instead of `join()`. What a waste of CPU time.

Comment: great. why is not flushing causing this?

Comment: "enter here" is only written to a buffer (std::cout is buffered!). This buffer is never written to stdout --> no output

Comment: @Bob See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274057/c-cout-and-cin-buffers-and-buffers-in-general