# C++ Binary file - Same number written over and over

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

So I have this code, pretty straightforward:

```
struct Item{
int x;
};


int main(){

    ofstream dat("file.bin", ios::binary);

    Item chair;

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
           chair.x = i;
           dat.write((char*)&chair, sizeof(Item));
    }


ifstream dat2("file.bin", ios::binary);

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    dat2.read((char*)&chair, sizeof(Item));
    cout << chair.x << endl;
}


return 0; }
```

When I run this code, even though I always set the chair.x to the value of i, when I read the entries in the second for loop, every .x value that is read is 19. Here is the result, since I'm bad at explaining:

[image: Code result]
it should however be 0, 1, 2, ... 19. Where am I getting this wrong?

Comment: Try to close ostream before opening file for reading

Comment: @Elalfer I feel like an idiot. It's working now. Thanks!

Comment: In the future, check for I/O errors.  This would have let you know that you were wrong about "every .x value that is read is 19" and that in fact nothing at all was being read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see, you are reading and writing the same file; why don't you [flush](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/flush) or [close](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/close) the stream before reading the file again. See [A good explanation to buffering in streams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9275346/1621391)

```
int main(){

    ofstream dat("file.bin", ios::binary);

    Item chair;

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
           chair.x = i;
           dat.write((char*)&chair, sizeof(Item));
    }
    dat.flush();      //Add this here
    //dat.close();    //or this


    ifstream dat2("file.bin", ios::binary);

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        dat2.read((char*)&chair, sizeof(Item));
        cout << chair.x << endl;
    }


return 0;
}
```