# Buffer flushing: "\n" vs. std::endl

Tags: c++, optimization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++: “std::endl” vs “\n”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n)

In *Accelerated C++*, two things are mentioned:

1. Most systems take a significant amount of time to write characters to an output device. Because of this, C++ accumulates characters to be written in a buffer and waits for the buffer to be flushed.
2. One way a buffer can be flushed is if we explicitly tell it to do so by using `std::endl`.

This made me wonder: Obviously the benefits would be **very** small and unnoticeable for everything except the largest of outputs, but is using `"\n"` faster than using `std::endl`, or does `"\n"` also flush a buffer?

Comment: Yes, this is an implementation detail, so you won't get a definite answer. My guess is that it makes a difference in most implementations, but this does not have to be true.

Comment: @Carl -- Admittedly, I did not, I wouldn't even know how to. I was reading the book and I was curious, so I thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using '\n' does not flush the buffer and is indeed faster than using std::endl.

In typical I/O, output is buffered before it's written to the intended device. This way, when writing to slow to access devices(like files), it doesn't have to access the device after every single character. Flushing "flushes" the buffer onto the device, causing a definite performance overhead.

-Adapted from: [C++ - endl and flushing the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751972/c-endl-and-flushing-the-buffer)

Comment: For some [generally] very small value of "faster" ;-)

Comment: @pst: well, when outputting large quantity of data to file it may actually kill the performance (it happened to me once when writing some tens of MBs of data in CSV).

Comment: @MatteoItalia True, I was not thinking of the inverse :(

Comment: @MatteoItalia: On other hand iostream isn't the fastest way to output something, so there will many other things that'll impact performance negatively.

Comment: @SigTerm: iostreams has a horrible design, but in the `g++` implementation in several occasions I found out that it was slightly faster than C stdio.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add that I think meaning of writing `'\n'` to the stream could be different from writing `std::endl`/`std::flush` in third-party libraries.

For example, I'm using ostream-based logger in current project. That logger uses `std::stringstream` functionality for output formatting, but has overridden manipulators for flushing. This allows to write `'\n'` to the log without flushing and simplifies code.

Here is a pseudocode sample:

```
class MyStream
{
    // [cut]
    std::stringstream m_buffer;
    // [cut]
};

// friends:
template <typename Printable>
MyStream& operator<<(MyStream& stream, const Printable& value)
{
     stream.m_buffer << value;
}

typedef decltype(std::flush) TManipulator;
template <>
MyStream& operator<<(MyStream& stream, const TManipulator& manipulator)
{
     if ( manipulator == std::flush || manipulator == std::endl )
         stream.sendLogLine();
     else
         stream.m_buffer << manipulator;
}

// usage sample
void main()
{
    getLoggerStream() << "hello" << std::endl;
}
```

P.S. I didn't like to subclass `std::stringstream`, so MyStream is an adapter. If I want to make `'\n'` flushing I should reimplement much more functionality including `char*`, `std::string` and other specializations.