# C++ getline not able to take input

Tags: c++

I am trying to read in a sentence to unscramble, however something is going wrong. When I enter no character it'll print out "The sentence is" and "Decoded sentence is", but when I enter one or more characters it'll just sit there and do nothing. I don't think it could be an error with MySentence class because it does not even print "The sentence is".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "MySentence.h"
#include "Corpus.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Corpus corp;
    std::cout << "The proportions are: ";
    for(int i = 0; i<26; i++) {
            cout << corp.proportion(i+97) <<", ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter sentence terminated by <ENTER> ";

    string s= "";
    getline(cin, s);
    cout << "The sentence is " << s;
    MySentence sent(s);
    sent.decode(corp);
    cout << endl << "Deoded sentence is: " << sent.sentence;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you press enter after typing the characters?

Comment: Yeah it just goes to a new line.

Comment: Try this: `cout << "The sentence is " << s << endl;`

Comment: As @n.m. meant to say, it helps to flush the output before executing statements that might hang.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by n.m. try to add an endl at the end of the line

cout << "The sentence is " << s << endl;

since it is possible that the buffer is not being flushed and the problem is in the class MySentence.

An interesting post that might help would be 
[Buffer flushing: "\n" vs. std::endl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9651311/buffer-flushing-n-vs-stdendl)

Comment: Ok that worked a little. It prints "The sentence is " plus whatever I enter but stops there. It never gets to "Decoded sentence..."

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger (e.g. gdb) to step through the code and see where it is hanging?