# How can I print a string with newline without flushing the buffer?

Tags: c, printf, flush

When I do this (note the included `\n`):

```
printf("Something.\n");
```

I would like it *not* to flush the buffer. I would like to manually flush it later.
Is this possible?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30967642/how-can-i-print-a-newline-without-flushing-the-buffer) sort of asks the same thing, but asks about C++ instead of C. I don't see how I could gather how to do this in C by reading the answers to that question (so it's not a duplicate).

Comment: [Here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Controlling-Buffering.html) are your options.

Comment: @EugeneSh. So what you're saying is `stdout` is in `_IOLBF` mode (line buffering) and I should use `setvbuf` to switch it to `_IOFBF` mode (full buffering)?

Comment: Try it and tell us..

Comment: @EugeneSh. I can see how it would be used but I'm not sure exactly how to use it (specifically, I don't know what to pass for the `char *buf` parameter). Could you answer the question?

Comment: If you read the documentation, it explains that. Just pass NULL for the `buf` parameter and `setvbuf` will take care of it for you.

Comment: @EugeneSh. But I'm using `stdout` right? Why would I want to allocate any new memory? There is probably something about this stuff that I don't understand.

Comment: @QuintinSteiner: You are expected to do some research on your own. Namely reading the documentation and search for further information. If you have rpoblems with the C language, read a C book. We are no tutoring site, forum, etc. but a Q&A site. You ask a **specific** question, showing reasonable effort and providing all required information, you might get an answer. That's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the comments, [setvbuf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/setvbuf) can be used to change the buffering of any file stream, including `stdout`.

Here is a simple example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOFBF, 0);
    printf("hello world\n");
    sleep(5);
}
```

The example uses `setvbuf` to make `stdout` fully buffered. Which means it will not immediately output upon encountering a newline. The example will only display the output after the `sleep` (flush on exit). Without the `setvbuf` the output will be displayed before the `sleep`.