# Is it necessary for endl to flush buffer？

Tags: c++, flush

According to the definition of `endl`, it is used to insert a new-line character and flush the stream. And I remember that if a new line is inserted, then the buffer will be flushed automatically. If so, why do `endl` still need to flushes the stream after inserting a new line.

Comment: It's the same basic reason why water is wet: the C++ standard says so.

Comment: o o, "if a new line is inserted, then the buffer will be flushed automatically" --> common.  Are you sure it is C++ specified?

Comment: @chux - Reinstate Monica I think so because c does

Comment: You will find a  common trick when you don't want to spend the time flushing a stream is to output a newline rather than employing `endl`. It's a common trick because most of the time it works. It's usually only data sent to the user's terminal that's auto-flushed on newline, and that's a decision made by the implementation.

Comment: @oo "because c does" --> It is certainly not specified in C.

Comment: C quite notoriously doesn't have `endl`, so the comparison is a bit weak.

Comment: You'll probably find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/stdendl-vs-n), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30967642/how-can-i-print-a-newline-without-flushing-the-buffer) interesting reads.

Comment: If you're writing to the terminal it is common practice to just append a line feed. For example `std::cout << "Hello World\n";`. Or `std::cout << "Hello " << variable << '\n';`.

Comment: *" if a new line is inserted, then the buffer will be flushed automatically"* - I don't believe this is true. I have no idea why an implementation would make a special case for `\n`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> if a new line is inserted, then the buffer will be flushed automatically

Not necessarily, and not for all streams.  It's common for `std::cout` (and the standard output stream it sends data to) to be line-buffered, but not universal.  Some implementations, for example, only line-buffer stdout if output is going to a terminal, and fully-buffer it otherwise (if output is redirected to a pipe, for example).

And that's just for standard output.  Other streams like file I/O are almost always fully-buffered and the buffer will only be flushed when it either fills up or its flushed explicitly.

Comment: And, to be clear, flushing the output buffer is rarely useful, and often a performance killer. For console output it doesn't make much difference, but for file I/O, don't mess with buffering unless you know what you're doing.