# Dev-C++ is not showing ant output for this program

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, nodes, dev-c++

When I ran the below code in dev C++ the output is empty, Even though online compilers are doing well. Is there a specific error in my code or do I have change dev C++ settings

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

class node //node definition
{
    public:
        int data;
        node* next;
        node(int value=0)
        {
            data=value;
            
        }
};

node* insert(node* head,int data)  //node insertion 
{
    node* ins=new node(data);
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        return ins;
    }
    else
    {
        node* ptr=head;
        while(head->next!=NULL)
        head=head->next;
        
        head->next=ins;
        ins->next=NULL;
        return ptr;
    }
    
}

void print(node* head)  //printing the values of linked list
{
    while(head!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<head->data<<" ";
        head=head->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector <int> a{1,2,3,6,8};
    node* list=NULL;
    for(int x:a)
    {

        list=insert(list,x);
    }
    print(list);
}
```

[image: Output:]

Can anyone resolve the issue?

Comment: Related question: [`endl` and flushing the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751972/endl-and-flushing-the-buffer). Also please consider reading [Why is `using namespace std;` considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: Long story short: I recommend adding `std::cout << std::endl;` at the end of the `print` function.

Comment: Short story: You don't default-initialize the `next` member of your structure. So, when you call `insert` the first time, the `next` member of your `new` structure could be anything at all. The online compiler(s) may accidentally give that a `nullptr` (zero) value, but you can't rely on it.

Comment: Additionally I recommend to check, if the exe-file that you are calling, is the correct one. Maybe it will be in some debug or other sub directory. Please check your compiler for the correct output path settings. Only maybe . . .

Comment: No head no print, you don't assign to head when head is null.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to initialize the `next` member of a newly allocated `node`, hence your list has an undefined (and potentially illegal) pointer value at the end after the first node insertion.

From that point on the **behavior** of the program is **undefined**.

A fix is completeing the constructor:

```cpp
        node(int value=0)
        {
            data = value;
            next = nullptr;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. But I am still wondering why online compilers executed properly even when the next is not initialized with nullptr?

Comment: @manaschinta An _Undefined_ Behavior is a behavior that is Undefined. Neither the language standard, nor specific compiler, nor the runtime library specification or the execution environment _defines_ what should or may happen. The program may crash immediately or it may work pretty well. It may also pretend to work, but silently destroy its vital data somewhere else and crash at some apparently unrelated operation. The behavior needn't be predictable or even repeatable.

Comment: @manaschinta _Possibly_ online compilers use a clearing allocator, which initializes memory with zeros, thus causing pointer members be `nullptr` (which, AFAIK, is itself implementation-dependent). But that is not guaranteed and, as you experienced it, needn't work same in different environments or on different machines. It may also change without prior notice, because it is not even defined the particular behavior will remain constant.